# MongoDB Java driver Filters.expr produces incorrect filter expression

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

I am trying to build a filter expression that looks like this:

```
{ $expr:{ $gt:['$bal1', '$bal2'] } }
```

using the Filter.expr function:

```
Bson filter = Filters.expr( gt("$bal1", "$bal2") );
BsonDocument doc = filter.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, collection.getCodecRegistry());
System.out.println(doc.toJson());
```

this produces the following json:

```
{ "$expr" : { "$bal1" : { "$gt" : "$bal2" } } }
```

Clearly that's not right.  Is there some way of creating this query using Java static import interfaces, or am I stuck having to construct strings manually?  I'm new to Mongo, and I can't imagine that everyone is building strings by hand - any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

MongoDB Java driver 3.6.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) takes aggregation comparison functions. So you can't use the regular query builder.

Unfortunately, you just have to use `Document.parse` to parse the aggregation comparison string.

```
Bson filter = Filters.expr( Document.parse(" { $gt: [ \"$bal1\" , \"$bal2\"] } ") );
```

Compare [`query operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) vs [`aggregation comparison operators`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-comparison/).

Check the implementation [jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2617) for more details.

Comment: Perfect.  I found a small refinement is to use single quote instead of double quote (keeps the escape sequences out of the string):  Document.parse(" { $gt: [ '$bal1', '$bal2' ] } ")